# Use Moxy as default JAXB Implementation

Tags: xml, json, jaxb, moxy

In order to use Moxy as JAXB Implementation, one has to add a file called jaxb.properties in the folder with the domain classes of the application and include the following line

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Is it possible to make moxy the default for the project ? In case I have many different folders with annotated domain classes in which folder should I put this file?

Comment: Nope unless it Moxy gets bundled with the JDK

Comment: @Pangea - That's not entirely true: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13254722/383861

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan - The point I am trying to make is that it is not possible without any changes. If not this option then there is another. you can't avoid the config.

Comment: @Pangea - True with the exception of WebLogic where MOXy is the default JAXB implementation and configuration is necessary to use the RI as the JAXB provider.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan - point taken. But this is just for the app server though right. Is it also true for their jdk? jrockit or something.

Comment: @Pangea - At the current time the JDK contains a package renamed version of the JAXB RI.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

MOXy is already the default JAXB implementation in WebLogic 12.1.1:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/eclipselink-moxy-is-jaxb-provider-in.html

In other environments you could also leverage the `META-INF/services` mechanism to specify MOXy as the default JAXB provider:

1. Create a JAR that contains a file called `javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext` in the directory `META-INF/services`
2. The contents of the `javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext` file must be `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory`
3. Add that jar to your classpath.

Comment: Does it need to be in a different jar? Am I not allowed to do that in my current project? This is very annoying...should I have to create a new jar only for the purpose?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 - It doesn't need to be in a separate jar.  Note that once you put the `META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext` on the class path MOXy will become the default JAXB implementation for all applications sharing that class path.

Comment: Thanks. I believe it would be useful to add that to the eclipse link page on the wiki

Comment: I have added a file inside META-INF/services named javax.xml.bindJAXBContext inside my project, and set the content of this file to org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory, but still I don't get moxy used

Comment: Make sure the file is called `javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext` and not `javax.xml.bindJAXBContext`.  In your comment you are missing a `.` between `bind` and `JAXBContext`.  I just retried these steps in Eclipse and got MOXy as the provider of the `JAXBContext`.

Comment: This is solved, however it does not solve the fact that it complains about a missing no arg constructor for an @XmlTransient element :)

Comment: @Edmondo1984 - Could you enter a bug for that issue you are seeing (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EclipseLink)?  Also which version of EclipseLink are you using (current version is 2.4.1).

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I am unable to update the broken link to MOXy as it not at least a 6 character change. http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#moxy