# Using Moxy with Metro in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, moxy, java-metro-framework

due to company requirements we can't use Glassfish as application server. Nevertheless I would like to use Moxy. So I tried to get the new Metro-version (https://blogs.oracle.com/mgrebac/entry/metro_2_2_jaxb_2) to work with a tomcat 7. I managed it to bootstrap Moxy using Spring like it is described in the metro documentation (http://metro.java.net/guide/user-guide.html#springa) but I didn't manage it to get it to work with Moxy.

I've tried the solution mentioned in the metro documentation (http://metro.java.net/2.2/guide/ch17.html) and the solution mentioned here ([Use Moxy as default JAXB Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253874/use-moxy-as-default-jaxb-implementation)).

But the most I could get out of it was the following exception:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingException: Unknown JAXBContext implementation: class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.getJAXBFactory(BindingContextFactory.java:207)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.create(BindingContextFactory.java:149)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.create(JAXBMessage.java:160)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAP11Fault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:423)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAPFaultMessage(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:200)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAPFaultMessage(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:188)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:391)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:640)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:263)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:218)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:159)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:194)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet.doPost(WSSpringServlet.java:52)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

My test webservice was:

```
@WebService
public class TestService {
    public String sayHello() throws JAXBException {
        System.out.println(org.eclipse.persistence.Version.getVersion());
        JAXBContext c = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestPojo.class);
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

And yes the the moxy jars (org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.4.0.jar, org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.4.0.jar, org.eclipse.persistence.asm-3.3.1.v201206041142.jar) are on the classpath.

Thx for help

JayBee

Comment: Got the same problem, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the JAX-WS `Provider` mechanism to leverage [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php):

**Example Web Service**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.util.JAXBSource;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.ws.*;

@ServiceMode(Service.Mode.PAYLOAD)
@WebServiceProvider(
    portName = "FindCustomerPort",
    serviceName = "FindCustomerService",
    targetNamespace = "http://service.jaxws.blog/",
    wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/FindCustomerService.wsdl")
public class FindCustomerService implements Provider<Source> {

    private JAXBContext jaxbContext;

    public FindCustomerService() {
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(FindCustomerResponse.class,
                    FindCustomerRequest.class);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new WebServiceException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Source invoke(Source request) throws WebServiceException {
        try {
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            FindCustomerRequest fcRequest = (FindCustomerRequest) unmarshaller
                    .unmarshal(request);

            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.setId(fcRequest.getArg0());
            customer.setFirstName("Jane");
            customer.setLastName("Doe");

            FindCustomerResponse response = new FindCustomerResponse();
            response.setValue(customer);

            return new JAXBSource(jaxbContext, response);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new WebServiceException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/02/leveraging-moxy-in-your-web-service-via.html

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer. But this seems to me to be a very low-level approach where I have to do a lot of things by hand. Probably there is an answer to the simple question why **JAXBContext.newInstance** already knows that we have a **org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext** but then can't find the right factory ?