# Spring Boot + JAXB MOXY

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I'm trying to use MOXY with Spring Boot. To that end I included the following in my Gradle build file:

`org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.moxy:2.7.1`

And added a `jaxb.properties` file with:

> javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory

within a JAXB annotated classes directory. However, the context still is:

> JAXB context: class
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl

Any ideas on the problem/solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I actually used the solution provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13254722/364244
The `META-INF` folder in Spring Boot should be in the `resources` directory, full path is `src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and fixed by check `jaxb.properties` file's location.

When you create new **JAXBContext**, **ContextFinder** will find property files with ClassLoader by its expected propFileName.

If `ClassLoader` cannot find any property files, then `internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl` will be used.

So please check your `contextPath` and your property files location.

In my case, directory name and hierarchy structure was wrong.