# In JAXB, How can I set node value to attribute value for a string field?

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb, moxy

I need to send this certain type of xml message to a web service;

```
<Personel>
    <name value="HelpMe"/>
    <surname value="Please"/>
</Personel>
```

My code is like;

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Personel")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Personel{

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "surname")
    String surname;
}
```

But this code produces xml like;

```
<Personel>
    <name>HelpMe<name/>
    <surname>Please<surname/>
</Personel>
```

I couldn't find a proper way to do this without create name and surname classes with attribute fields named "value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found moxy implementation of jaxb as a solution. It gives the capability giving default attribute keys.

Answer about using moxy as default jaxb implementation : [Use Moxy as default JAXB Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253874/use-moxy-as-default-jaxb-implementation/13254722#13254722)

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Personel")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Personel{

    @XmlPath("name/@value")
    String name;

    @XmlPath("surname/@value")
    String surname;
}
```

So above code generates the following xml as I desired,

```
<Personel>
    <name value="HelpMe"/>
    <surname value="Please"/>
</Personel>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need below format.

```
<Personel>
    <name value="HelpMe"/>
    <surname value="Please"/>
</Personel>
```

Create PersonelName and PersonelSurname and then use these classes as XmlElement in Personel classs.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PerosonelName {

   @XmlValue
    String value;

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    String name;

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PersonelSurname {

   @XmlValue
    String value;

    @XmlElement(name = "surname")
    String surname;

}


@XmlRootElement(name = "Personel")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Personel{

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    String PerosonelName ;

    @XmlElement(name = "surname")
    String PersonelSurname ;
}
```

Comment: how can I achieve it **without create name and surname classes** ?